# Keypoint matching just works two times...? (java opencv)

Tags: java, opencv, image-recognition, keypoint

I have a very strange problem. I'm using this code to detect an image in another one (java opencv):

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
public void startRecognition() {
    //load images, I want to find img_object in img_scene
    Mat img_scene = Highgui.imread("D:/opencvws/ImageRecognition/src/main/resources/ascene.jpg");
    Mat img_object = Highgui.imread("D:/opencvws/ImageRecognition/src/main/resources/aobj1.jpg");
    run++;
    System.out.println("RUN NO: " + run);

    //init detector
    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);

    //keypoint detection for both images (keyponts_scene for img_scene, keypoint_object for img_object)
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_object = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_scene  = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img_object, keypoints_object);
    detector.detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);
    System.out.println("OK: " + keypoints_object.total());
    System.out.println("SK: " + keypoints_scene.total());

    //extractor init
    DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(2); //2 = SURF;
    Mat descriptor_object = new Mat();
    Mat descriptor_scene = new Mat() ;
    //Compute descriptors
    extractor.compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptor_object);
    extractor.compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptor_scene);

    //init matcher
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.FLANNBASED); // 1 = FLANNBASED
    matcher.clear();
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

    //match both descriptors
    matcher.match(descriptor_object, descriptor_scene, matches);
    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();

    //calc min/max dist
    Double max_dist = 0.0;
    Double min_dist = 100.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < descriptor_object.rows(); i++){
        Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;
        if(dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if(dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    //filter good matches
    LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
    MatOfDMatch gm = new MatOfDMatch();

    //good match = distance > 2*min_distance ==> put them in a list
    for(int i = 0; i < descriptor_object.rows(); i++){
        if(matchesList.get(i).distance < 2*min_dist){
            good_matches.addLast(matchesList.get(i));
        }
    }
    //List -> Mat
    gm.fromList(good_matches);

    //mat for resulting image
    Mat img_matches = new Mat();

    //filter keypoints (use only good matches); First in a List, iterate, afterwards ==> Mat
    LinkedList<Point> objList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    LinkedList<Point> sceneList = new LinkedList<Point>();

    List<KeyPoint> keypoints_objectList = keypoints_object.toList();
    List<KeyPoint> keypoints_sceneList = keypoints_scene.toList();

    for(int i = 0; i<good_matches.size(); i++){
        objList.addLast(keypoints_objectList.get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
        sceneList.addLast(keypoints_sceneList.get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
    }

    MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
    obj.fromList(objList);

    MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();
    scene.fromList(sceneList);

    //calc transformation matrix; method = 8 (RANSAC) ransacReprojThreshold=3
    Mat hg = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene, 8,3);

    //init corners
    Mat obj_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);
    Mat scene_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);
    //obj
    obj_corners.put(0, 0, new double[] {0,0});
    obj_corners.put(1, 0, new double[] {img_object.cols(),0});
    obj_corners.put(2, 0, new double[] {img_object.cols(),img_object.rows()});
    obj_corners.put(3, 0, new double[] {0,img_object.rows()});

    //transform obj corners to scene_img (stored in scene_corners)
    Core.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners,scene_corners, hg);

    //move points for img_obg width to the right to fit the matching image
    Point p1 = new Point(scene_corners.get(0,0)[0]+img_object.cols(), scene_corners.get(0,0)[1]);
    Point p2 = new Point(scene_corners.get(1,0)[0]+img_object.cols(), scene_corners.get(1,0)[1]);
    Point p3 = new Point(scene_corners.get(2,0)[0]+img_object.cols(), scene_corners.get(2,0)[1]);
    Point p4 = new Point(scene_corners.get(3,0)[0]+img_object.cols(), scene_corners.get(3,0)[1]);

    //create the matching image
    Features2d.drawMatches(
            img_object,
            keypoints_object, 
            img_scene,
            keypoints_scene, 
            gm, 
            img_matches);
    //draw lines to the matching image
    Core.line(img_matches, p1 , p2, new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
    Core.line(img_matches, p2, p3, new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
    Core.line(img_matches, p3, p4, new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
    Core.line(img_matches, p4, p1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);


    // resizing...
    Mat resizeimage = new Mat();
    Size sz = new Size(1200, 1000);
    Imgproc.resize(img_matches, img_matches, sz);
    panel1.setimagewithMat(img_matches);

    frame1.repaint();

    //tried to prevent any old references to mix up new calculation 
    matcher.clear();
    img_matches = new Mat();
    img_object = new Mat();
    img_scene = new Mat();
    keypoints_object = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    keypoints_scene = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    hg = new Mat();
}
```

If I run the startRecognition methode twice (the opencv library is loaded at the startup) in my running application i get the same result for both recognitions. For the third try it detects other keypoints and calculates another transformation matrix (hg). Examples:

after 2nd try:

[image]

after 3rd:

[image: image description]

Can anyone explain why? Or tell me how to prevent it? When I restart the whole program, it will again detect 2 times correct and afterwards varying. After several tries it will again calculate the correct hg (from the first and seceond try). I can't figure out why this is happending.

Thanks in advance

gemorra

Comment: might this have to do with writing and loading the `test.yaml` in each `startRecognition()` call?

Comment: tested it again without the test.yaml file => same result...

Comment: are there any difference in input images or do you use the exact same images as input? Is any variable reused in the calls? Can you comment your code (within code) to tell what is done there and what variables are meant to hold what kind of information?

Comment: I use the exact same images as input. I updated the code above. I recognized that some keypoints, that are found change after the second run. So maybe the problem is somehow related to the keypoint detection. the number of found keypoints is always the same and also min_dist value never changes...

Comment: Not sure how Flann works but maybe it depends on the order of inserted descriptors? But SURF should be deterministic I guess, giving same features for same images...

Comment: I also tried Bruteforce => same result. What I don't understand is, that if I restart the whole program x times I get the exact same result for each restart. only when I recall the function the problem occours. That's the reason I thought it could have something to do with old references or linked native objects...