# Java OpenCV - extracting good matches from knnMatch

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to implement a very simple program for finding similarities between two images.

I am using the ORB feature detector and image descriptor for this task and I am identifying the matches using **knnMatch**:

```
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

// DETECTION
// first image
Mat img1 = Imgcodecs.imread(path1, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

// second image
Mat img2 = Imgcodecs.imread(path2, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

// MATCHING
// match these two keypoints sets
List<MatOfDMatch> matches = new ArrayList<MatOfDMatch>();
matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, 5);
```

I am able to draw the matches as follows:

```
// DRAWING OUTPUT
Mat outputImg = new Mat();
// this will draw all matches, works fine
Features2d.drawMatches2(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches, outputImg);

// save image
Imgcodecs.imwrite("result.jpg", outputImg);
```

The problem is that there are too many matches and it includes also those that are way off. I can't seem to find how to extract only the good matches (exceeding some threshold)? Could someone point me to the right direction or redirect me to some basic working example? I have spent several hours on this and seem to be lost..

### **EDIT:**

I tried looking at [Keypoint matching just works two times...? (java opencv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752497/keypoint-matching-just-works-two-times-java-opencv) but the standard (non-knn) match uses different structures and and I could not make it work.

Comment: A very similar question has been asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569386/opencv-filtering-orb-matches
Check it out. A nice answer have been given by @Darshan

Comment: @pyan Yes, I have seen this one. However, I can't seem to be able to rewrite the code to work with knn matcher.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, there are several methods to remove outliers and bad matches. I guess you found samples and tutorials with `match` instead of `knnMatch` utilizing some of those methods.

So, as you may know the difference is that `knnMatch` returns the n-best matches in `descriptor2` for each descriptor in `descriptor1`. Which means, instead of a list of matches you get a list of a list of matches. I guess this is the reason, why you had problems.

The main advantage using `knnMatch` is that you can perform a ratio test. So if the distances from one descriptor in `descriptor1` to the two best descriptors in `descriptor2` are similar it suggests that there are repetitive patterns in your images (e.g. the tips of a picket fence in front of grass). Thus, such matches aren't reliable and should be removed.
(I am not sure why you search for the five best matches - you pass 5 to `knnMatch` - for each descriptor. Rather search for two.)

If you now want to access the best match just for each descriptor, you just have to access the first element of the "sublists". In the following you'll find as a example a ratio test and a homography estimation using RANSAC (I replaced everything after your `knnMatch`):

```
    // ratio test
    LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
    for (Iterator<MatOfDMatch> iterator = matches.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        MatOfDMatch matOfDMatch = (MatOfDMatch) iterator.next();
        if (matOfDMatch.toArray()[0].distance / matOfDMatch.toArray()[1].distance < 0.9) {
            good_matches.add(matOfDMatch.toArray()[0]);
        }
    }

    // get keypoint coordinates of good matches to find homography and remove outliers using ransac
    List<Point> pts1 = new ArrayList<Point>();
    List<Point> pts2 = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for(int i = 0; i<good_matches.size(); i++){
        pts1.add(keypoints1.toList().get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
        pts2.add(keypoints2.toList().get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
    }

    // convertion of data types - there is maybe a more beautiful way
    Mat outputMask = new Mat();
    MatOfPoint2f pts1Mat = new MatOfPoint2f();
    pts1Mat.fromList(pts1);
    MatOfPoint2f pts2Mat = new MatOfPoint2f();
    pts2Mat.fromList(pts2);

    // Find homography - here just used to perform match filtering with RANSAC, but could be used to e.g. stitch images
    // the smaller the allowed reprojection error (here 15), the more matches are filtered 
    Mat Homog = Calib3d.findHomography(pts1Mat, pts2Mat, Calib3d.RANSAC, 15, outputMask, 2000, 0.995);

    // outputMask contains zeros and ones indicating which matches are filtered
    LinkedList<DMatch> better_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
        if (outputMask.get(i, 0)[0] != 0.0) {
            better_matches.add(good_matches.get(i));
        }
    }

    // DRAWING OUTPUT
    Mat outputImg = new Mat();
    // this will draw all matches, works fine
    MatOfDMatch better_matches_mat = new MatOfDMatch();
    better_matches_mat.fromList(better_matches);
    Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, better_matches_mat, outputImg);

    // save image
    Imgcodecs.imwrite("result.jpg", outputImg);
```

I hope this is sufficient as a example. Other filtering methods could be applied analogously. Do not hesitate to ask, if you have further questions.

**EDIT:**
The homography filtering is only valid if most of your keypoints are on the same plane in the scene, like a wall etc.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Do you know how the good matches could be used to compute some kind of score marking the similarity of those two compared pictures?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by similarity. If similar means that two pictures show different views of the same scene, then I think your approach is ok (depending on scene). Otherwise I would look for different ways. Can you give an example?

Comment: That's exactly my use-case. Same objects but taken from different angles. At the moment, I use the number of extracted good matches as a 'score' marking the similarity.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Maybe you can use #good matches/#all matches in order to get a ratio. (Otherwise two less structured images are likely less similar than two high structured ones with more keypoints)

Comment: Is this a bug if matOfDMatch.toArray()[0] gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBounds all the time?

Comment: hi @gfkri, I have an issue on this one. My post is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639964/java-opencv-using-knnmatch-with-findhomography-shows-duplicates